# Why are local reads so slow?

Tags: nodes, view

Why is it so slow to read data from the blockchain? Even if you use a local node, reading is slow.

Consider for example the following contract:

```
contract Test {
   bytes3[100] private largeArray;
   function test() public view returns(bytes3[100] memory) {
      return largeArray;
   }    
}
```

Executing that in Remix takes a few seconds. Add one more zero, and it basically kills the tab.

I was trying to google for an answer, browsed through for example https://www.anyblockanalytics.com/blog/why-reading-data-from-the-ethereum-blockchain-is-hard-and-how-to-speed-it-up/ , but in my opinion it fails to explain the slowness.

Answer (score 1):

Interpolated based on the answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/t9agei/why_retrieving_arrays_from_smart_contracts_is_so/ :

Reads are slow because of the way the data is stored. Scaling up hardware probably helps a bit, but not as much as anyone would like. Also, there is no general way to make reads faster.

What you can do is consider to either split the reading into multiple parts (into *pages*) or, if possible, retrieve only a smaller set of data based on some parameters.