# How can i test this solidity contract for(lets say) 5000 calls of the set function(.sol or .js)?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, testing, struct

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.16;

contract storeData {

    uint256 internal index = 0;

    struct IslandFcst {
        uint islandId;
        uint forecastDate;
        uint forecastValue;
    }
    mapping(uint256 => IslandFcst) islandfcst;

    function setData(uint _islandId, uint _forecastDate, uint                    _forecastValue)
    public {

        islandfcst[index] = IslandFcst(_islandId, _forecastDate, _forecastValue);

        index++;

    }

    function getData(uint256 _index) public view returns(uint, uint, uint)

    {
        return (
                    islandfcst[_index].islandId,
                    islandfcst[_index].forecastDate,
                    islandfcst[_index].forecastValue
               );
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to make an overload test to see how the function reacts to 5000 calls in a short amount of time?

Comment: yeap, exactly and moreover how much time is needed to perform this task!

Comment: Well, you can always just do it with a while or for loop and call the test 5000 times. Not an elegant solution but it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only performance metric you should be interested in is *gas cost*.

It doesn't really make sense to test your contract's speed. The time it takes for you to receive a result depends mostly on the used node's capacity, network latency and amount of data.

If you are using your own node (99% of developers don't - they use a service provider such as Infura or Alchemy) it *might* make *just a little bit* sense to test its performance. But, not really. It doesn't make sense to test the performance of service provider's nodes.

Reading data from the blockchain is slow, no matter what ([Why are local reads so slow?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123338/why-are-local-reads-so-slow)).