# Is it faster to access variables in bulk rather than requesting them one by one?

Tags: solidity

Suppose I have a smart contract with some public variables.

```
uint256 public foo = 5;
uint256 public bar = 10;
uint256 public baz = 10;

function values() public view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    return (foo, bar, baz);
}
```

Is it faster/more data efficient to call values() vs. accessing foo, bar and baz in three different calls?

Answer (score 1):

All data reads are [slow](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123338/why-are-local-reads-so-slow). I'm not 100% sure, but most likely it would be faster to access your `values` function, since it reads all the data in one go. Retrieving each data separately is forced to perform separate reads.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to benchmark this somehow reliably? I noticed that data reads sometimes load fast, but sometimes, I have to wait for several seconds to read the value.

Comment: sorry, don't really know